# Trigger Test Class with mock callout

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a before update trigger which makes a future callout. When i am writing the test class for it, i am updating the object in test method to achieve coverage for trigger. However this is causing error in test class execution and error says - "***You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.***"

Now i know i can't do dml before callout but without dml my trigger wont fire. I am not sure what i am missing here. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Trigger Snippet:

```
if(opp.stageName = 'Gained Commitment' && more conditions) 
{
    if(HelperClass.firstRun){
        // So that trigger dont fire twice 
        HelperClass.firstRun=false;
        List<Opportunity> op = new List<Opportunity>();
        op.add(Trigger.newMap.get(opportunityId));
        op[0].Commitment_Call_Type__c = 'Amount above threshold';
        op[0].Commitment_Lock__c = True;
        // future method called from below class *********
        SAPInterfaceCommitmentManager.sendOpportunity(op);
    }
}
```

Future webservice callout from above trigger:

```
@future(callout = true)
public static void SAPInterfaceCommitmentCallout (string JSON, ID id, String CallType) {
    // Webservice callout . . . 
}
```

Test Method:

```
static testMethod void unitTest1() {
    
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockTokenResponseSucess());
    Account acc = [select id from account where SAP_SoldTo_ID__c = :SAP_ID ];
    opportunity opp = [select id,Is_Proforma_Editable__c,SoldTo_Account_Credit_Block_Reason__c,Available_Credit_Acc_Curr__c,Opportunity_Total_Fees__c,Last_Credit_Check_Time__c from opportunity where SoldTo_Account__c=:acc.id ];
    opp.stageName = 'Gained Commitment';
    update opp;
    system.debug('opportunity values'+opp);
    Test.stopTest(); 
}
```

Comment: Providing the code and test class that you have right now would probably be helpful. The only thing that I can think of is that you're trying to work around the `@future` callout and end up calling it synchronously. If you're not using `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`, you likely should be.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to keep it short so didn't put entire code. Basically dml and callout is being happening in single transaction.

Comment: Did you tag `@future(callout = true)` to your static method `sendOpportunity` in the `SAPInterfaceCommitmentManager` class? I only see a `SAPInterfaceCommitmentCallout` method with the future annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger code calls a `sendOpportunity(op)` method in the `SAPInterfaceCommitmentManager` class. But I only see a `SAPInterfaceCommitmentCallout` method with the future annotation. Either call this method or tag `sendOpportunity(op)` with `@future`.